# Unable to get email when using Facebook login api in Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, api

I am trying to get the email of a profile that has made a login in my app but i have a problem with this.

In the function `onCompleted()` i ask for the email and it returns me the mail, if i make a Log i see that the mail isn't null, but only returns me something not null if i make the Log inside the `onCompleted()` function, outside it throws an error (`ailure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity`) and i get a `javaNullPointerException`.

Thanks for the help!

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    if (response.getError() != null) {
                        System.out.print("ERROR");
                    }
                    else {
                        fbUserMail = object.optString("email");
                        Log.d("email",fbUserMail); //THIS GETS ME THE EMAIL
                    }
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "email");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

            Log.d("emailoutside", fbUserMail); //THIS THROWS ME A NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            goMainActivity(profile,fbUserMail);
        }
```

Comment: Check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/31692794/3774906

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the email of a user from the facebook LoginButton widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603398/how-to-get-the-email-of-a-user-from-the-facebook-loginbutton-widget)

Answer (score 0):

My problem persists.

```
public class getProfileData extends AsyncTask<AccessToken,String,String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(AccessToken... params) {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(params[0], new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                Log.v("LoginScreen", response.toString());
                try {
                    name = object.getString("first_name");
                    surname = object.getString("last_name");
                    email = object.getString("email");
                    Log.d("name",name);
                    Log.d("surname",surname);
                    Log.d("email",email); //THIS GETS ME THE EMAIL
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,first_name,last_name,email");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAndWait();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Log.d("email",email); //THIS THROWS ME AN EXCEPTION
        if (profile != null) {
            Log.d("email", email); //THIS DOESN'T THROW NOTHING
            Intent main = new Intent(LoginScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            main.putExtra("name", profile.getFirstName());
            main.putExtra("surname", profile.getLastName());
            main.putExtra("imageUrl", profile.getProfilePictureUri(400,400).toString());
            main.putExtra("email", s);
            startActivity(main);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

I think that the problem comes from request.executeAndWait();